# Error cannot find symbol variable FileProvider package android.support.v4.content does not exist

Tags: android, compiler-errors, build.gradle, android-fileprovider

I'm using Android studio 3.5 gradle plugin 3.5.0 version 5.6.2

After cloning and importing  this [Scanlibrary](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo)

I'm facing these two errors

> error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
>
> error: cannot find symbol variable FileProvider

Any ideas?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.scanlibrary.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.capturedocf"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
}
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
   implementation'com.github.chernovdmitriy.injectionholder:appcompat:1.0.0'
   implementation project(path: ':scanlibrary')
 }
```

build.gradle(Module:scanlibrary)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk
            {
                moduleName "Scanner"
            }
}
sourceSets.main
        {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        }
 }
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.2'
}
```

PickImageFragement.java

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

public class PickImageFragment extends Fragment {
public void openCamera() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Uri tempFileUri = 
  FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                "com.scanlibrary.provider", // As defined in Manifest
                file);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempFileUri);
    } else {
        Uri tempFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempFileUri);
    }
```

Comment: That code is rather old. You will need to modify it to use AndroidX dependencies, and you will then be able to use `FileProvider` from AndroidX.

Comment: unfortunately I have no idea how to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by downgrading to sdk 28 then I added this code in my app build to find the source

```
allprojects {

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
    }
}
}
```

And then I saw there was java file who Had library missing so I imported the FileProvider and the error was gone

Answer (score 1):

your project support androidx and the library you are using does not support androidx , so you need to enable `jetifier` in your project ,
so to enable `jetifier`, add those two lines to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

the first line `android.useAndroidX=true` indicates that you want to start using AndroidX from now on
the second line `android.enableJetifier=true` indicates that you want to have tool support

Comment: They are already enabled ...my guess its sdk issue 29 may be too much for the library used

Comment: @Ishak Benaissa Note: With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components. see [support-library/setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup). We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.